# Converting User Item Rating Into Matrix Market Input format using Matlab or Python

Tags: python, matlab

Sir, I have a dataset in which entries are in the form

userid|itemid|rating

I want to change this rating into matrix market input format using matlab or python

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something like this in matlab (not checked yet the code, you might need a couple transposing too):

```
fid = fopen('exp.txt');
A = fscanf(fid, '%d|%d|%g', [3 inf]);
S = sparse(A(1,:), A(2,:), A(3,:))
```

[Reference on reading files.](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fscanf.html)
[Reference on sparse matrices.](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)