# Matlab: Load Users-Items-Ratings CSV into Ratings matrix

Tags: matlab, csv, matrix, recommendation-engine

I have the following CSV format for users rating items:

```
A1YS,8F20,3.0
A3TS,8320,2.0
A3BU,1905,5.0
A3BU,3574,4.0
A14X,185A,1.0
```

The columns are UserID,ItemID,Rating

I want to load it to a Matlab matrix with rows for users, columns for items and cell values will contain the ratings (unknown rating equals zero) in example:

```
      8F20,  1905,  3574,  185A
A1YS    3 ,    0 ,    0 ,    0 
A3TS    2 ,    0 ,    0 ,    0 
A3BU    0 ,    5 ,    4 ,    0 
A14X    0 ,    0 ,    0 ,    1
```

Another thing, actually the matrix can be formed as:

```
3 ,    0 ,    0 ,    0 
2 ,    0 ,    0 ,    0 
0 ,    5 ,    4 ,    0 
0 ,    0 ,    0 ,    1
```

I'm quite new to Matlab and tried some variations of:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13775907/1726419 and 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19613301/1726419

without big success - I'll be very thankful for any assistance.

**EDIT**:
What I've got so far is:

```
fid = fopen('ratings_sample.csv');
out = textscan(fid,'%s%s%d%d','delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);

c1 = out{1};
c2 = out{2};
c3 = out{3};
```

My problem is that I need duplicate removal of both `c1` & `c2` and to fill in properly the inner cells of the matrix. plus, I don't know if this is the proper way to load it.

Comment: You need to load the data first and then manipulate it to the shape you want. Did  you try textscan as in your 2nd example? If so show us how far you got and what didn't work?

Comment: Thanks,@Justin, I've uploaded what I've done so far my main issue is with rotating the vectors, duplicate removal and filling the data inside...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If UserID and ItemID are unique, you can use [`crosstab`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/crosstab.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
UserID = categorical(c1);
ItemID = categorical(c2);
Rating = crosstab(UserID,ItemID);
Rating(Rating==1) = c3;
```

and get:

```
Rating =
     3     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     2     5     0     0
     0     0     0     4     0
```

If you want to organize it in a table, you need to first convert the item's ID to a valid variable name (that starts with a letter):

```
Items = cellfun(@(s) ['Item_' s],c2,'un',0);
```

and then you can use a `table` to hold all the data:

```
Tbl = array2table(Rating,...
                  'RowNames',unique(c1,'stable'),...
                  'VariableNames',unique(Items,'stable'))
```

the result:

```
Tbl =
  4×5 table
            Item_8F20    Item_8320    Item_1905    Item_3574    Item_185A
            _________    _________    _________    _________    _________
    A1YS    3            0            0            0            0        
    A3TS    0            0            0            0            1        
    A3BU    0            2            5            0            0        
    A14X    0            0            0            4            0
```